# React Native, No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run my app in my physical device with USB, but when I run `react-native run-android` after building successfully it's showing `warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed.` I also run `adb devices` to check if my mobile is connect and it's showing

```
List of devices attached
4200336f97fc7483        device
```

and app in device just closing automaticallly. If my cable damage it wouldn't showed my files in my system but it's showing my device files too. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
adb -s 4200336f97fc7483 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Also, remember to turn on the USB Debuggin enabled on the phone, other important thing it's that you should check if the usb cable it's for data transmition or just for charge the phone

Thanks

Comment: no i did't wait i wil try that, yes debugging is on it's working fine since i started react native

Comment: Yes, I can transmit data with it

Comment: didn't worked, I think my device got damaged it's not working properly